# Tridion 2011: How to sort user list on publishing queue?

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

On Tridion 2011 SP1 HR1 publishing queue, I see user list is not sorted.

> **Is there a way to sort the user list or should I raise a ticket for a hot-fix?**

### Update:

To be more clear.

On Filter Publishing Task options --> User Dropdown, currently sorting is done based on `User Title` by default.

As a user, it's not appearing as sorted.

So, I'm looking for sorting the User Dropdown based on `User Description`.

Please suggest How can I achieve this.

Comment: Are you using 2011 GA or SP1 ? 2011 GA in the publishing queue the user is not automatically selected but the list should be sorted by User Title. I believe(need to check) in 2011 SP1 user selection is fixed. Also, in publishing queue what you see is User Description but not the User Title so in a way they are sorted by User Title.

Comment: @RamG: You are right. we have installed SP1 and also HR but user dropdown is not sorted based on user description.

Comment: @RamG: I have once again tested with SP1 HR1 fresh install. But NO LUCK. Sorting is still done based on User Title.

Comment: Sorry If I wan't clear in my previous message. The list only sorted by user Title but not User Description (this is same in all Tridion releases). In SP1, the CM Slogged in user is already pre-selected in the the dropdown (not in 2011 GA). What is the use case for list to be sorted by User Description.? As Nick mentioned below people use Description field for various things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort users in User dropdown on Publishing Queue popup could be achieved by creating new custom extension.
You add new js file to Publishing Queue popup group where you can overwrite `Tridion.Cme.Views.PublishQueue.USER_DROPDOWN_HEAD_PATH` property. It should point to Dropdown xml definition file. You'll need to create your own Dropdown xml definition file (by copying existing `WebUI/Editors/CME/Xml/ListDefinitions/PublishQueueUserDropdown-head.xml`) and add new node `/list:listDefinition/list:rows/list:defaultSortField` with value `@Description`.

Comment: That's perfect. Thanks Boris.

Comment: Great example, Boris. I see this works for things like Search Folders (ListSearchItems.xml) as well.

Answer (score 6):

On 2011 SP1 the user dropdown in the Filter Publishing Tasks options is sorted alphabetically by the username (User Title).  And if you select "all", then in the Publishing Tasks list you can sort the task by username by clicking on the column heading.  There is also a little funnel icon where you can filter further.

I am pretty sure this is by-design, so there will most likely not be a hotfix for this.  You can submit an idea to have this feature implemented in one of the next releases via the Ideas site on sdltridionworld, or build a custom gui extension to do specifically what you need.

Comment: Sorry i think some misunderstanding. Currently on filter publishing tasks options - User dropdown is sorted based on `User Title` by default. Actually I'm looking for sorting based on `User Description` value.

Comment: In this Tridion release you will need to build this functionality custom.  I don't think Tridion will provide this functionality by default because various clients use the Description field for various purposes, and sorting by it isn't applicable for everybody.